# How to automatically pass the first row of a ListView field to an EditText field

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-intent, android-edittext

I am creating a simple app trying to learn functions and implement basic features.  My main aim is to have voice command working where I open an app and simply say go to next page and then it does so etc.  Is there a way of doing this using android studio as I havn't come across any examples.

I have managed to get voice recognition working and it provides the speech to text statements in the ListView.  I am trying to create a simple app at the moment with a login page where the user can either type the correct credentials and proceed to the next page or use speech to text to fill up the credentials which if correct automatically go to the next page.

My question is whether there is a way to automatically pass in the first row statement in ListView into the username field which is currently an EditText field followed by pressing the login button automatically after 1-2 seconds.  I have attached the main java file to do this and will really appreciate some help with the code.  Please note at the moment I am just using a username for verification and password field is not important.

```
ListView lv;
static final int check = 1111;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvVoiceReturn);
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bVoice);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);///////////////////
}

public void onButtonClick(View v)
{
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Blogin)
    {
        EditText a = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFusername);
        String str = a.getText().toString();


        //Go to the next 'Display' window or activity if the person enters the correct username which is not case sensitive
        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("next"))
        {
            Intent userintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Display.class);
            startActivity(userintent);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect Information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Please Repeat Again");
    startActivityForResult(i, check);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == check && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
        //??String selectedFromList = (lv.getItemAtPosition(position))////////
    }


    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
a.setText((String)lv.getItemAtPosition(0));

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            b.performClick();
                        }
                    }, 2000);
```

The first line sets your editText from the first row of listView and then the [handler](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Handler.html) performs the event 2000 ms i.e 2 sec later.

Full code :

```
ListView lv;
static final int check = 1111;
Button b;
EditText a;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvVoiceReturn);
    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bVoice);
    a = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFusername);

    b.setOnClickListener(this);///////////////////
}

public void onButtonClick(View v)
{
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Blogin)
    {
        String str = a.getText().toString();


        //Go to the next 'Display' window or activity if the person enters the correct username which is not case sensitive
        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("next"))
        {
            Intent userintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Display.class);
            startActivity(userintent);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect Information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Please Repeat Again");
    startActivityForResult(i, check);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == check && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
        //??String selectedFromList = (lv.getItemAtPosition(position))////////

        a.setText((String)lv.getItemAtPosition(0));

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            b.performClick();
                        }
                    }, 2000);
    }


    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

PS: If the answer helps then please accept it.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, I'm not sure exactly where to add this into the code.  Do I need to specify username field anywhere 'TFusername' and assign 'Blogin' button to the 2000ms event handler?

Comment: I have copy pasted it into the java file now and handler was giving an issue so I pressed ALT+Enter and selected java.util.logging.Handler but the postDelayed is giving "Cannot resolve method"?

Comment: No not logging , the other handler os handler something

Comment: okay, I think we are almost there.  So the ListView is now appearing in EditText but after every 2000ms it is pressing the speak button 'bVoice' and not the login button 'Blogin'

Comment: Oh I confused the button, then just declare your other button like    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Blogin);
 this and then call button.performClick()

Comment: I'll check it in 2 hours (in a meeting), if it works I'll select your answer as correct. Thanks a lot.  By the way is there a way to start voice recognition automatically without clicking a button, similar to how Google now answers a question by saying 'OK Google'?

Comment: Of course, basically by clicking the button you are performing a set of events. If you perform those set of events after any action you will get the same result. So in this case you don't even need to have a button. Instead of button.performClick() if you write the code that you wrote inside the onButtonClick method you will get same result.

Comment: For correcting the button to Blogin, is it just one line I change?

Comment: Yes, as I said -->  button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Blogin); and button.perfromClick(); instead of b.performClick()

Comment: Thank you very much for your help varunkr.  I have learned a lot.  Hopefully this helps others in the future.  Also is there a way to trigger the speak button rather than clicking it so that it is 100% hands free such as saying 'ok google' or just 'ok go to' followed by recording the speech to the ListView which then goes into the EditText?

Comment: which is the speak button, can't see in ur code? what does it do ? But I am sure this can be done, nothing is impossible in android, unless it really breaks something. I think you are pretty new to it !! keep trying !!

Comment: Yes I am fairly new, the bVoice button is what triggers speak recognition using the Google API English free form.  I'm wanting to trigger the voice command without touching a button but trigger using voice.  Your expertise and guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I haven't worked on speech api so I don't know the exact function !